# Trying to pseudo-sync 2 computers - why folders renamed?

Tags: windows-7, robocopy

Trying to pseudo-sync 2 computers - why folders renamed?

Windows 7 - new computer
Vista - old computer

I create a new folder `OldComputerDesktop` in `C:\Users\joeblow`.

I execute this:

```
robocopy.EXE \\us0003039-v004\c$\Users\joeblow\Desktop C:\Users\joeblow\OldComputerDesktop /XJ /E /NP >> syncfiles.log
```

When I look at `C:\Users\joeblow` with Windows Explorer and I see two `Desktop` folders - one is the "real"/original Desktop folder and the other is my folder originally named `OldComputerDesktop` but now is named `Desktop`. I verified this by right-clicking to see Properties and going to the Sharing tab (where I see the word `OldComputerDesktop`).

What explains this renaming behaviour? How do I prevent it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the Desktop folder is a "special" folder.

This is controlled by a hidden file inside the folder called `desktop.ini`

This tells Windows Explorer to show a different name than the actual folder name (it also specifies the special icon which is shown instead of the standard folder icon).

(You can prove this by opening Command Promt and running a `dir` command in the `C:\Users\joeblow\` folder which will show the real folder names)

Because you have copied the `desktop.ini` file from `Desktop` into `OldComputerDesktop` Windows Explorer will read it and display the name as Desktop.

You can either delete the `desktop.ini` filer or edit it in Notepad or any other text editor and remove the line:

```
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21769
```

You also see this behaviour with `Documents`, `Favourites`, `Pictures`, `Music`, `Videos` (and others) being prepended with `My` in Windows Explorer.